# why failed to forward public ip to docker NAT ip

Tags: networking, docker, iptables

For example, on the physical machine:

```
# ip addr
5: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 ..
    inet 10.32.230.90/24 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.32.230.61/24 scope global secondary eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 
    link/ether 02:42:65:1b:b0:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0
```

"10.32.230.90" is the main IP of this machine, and "10.32.230.61" is secondary added with "ip addr add 10.32.230.61/24 dev eth2".

After creating a docker instance, with IP = 172.17.0.10, I add the following rules to connect native IP with secondary IP:

```
# iptables -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.32.230.61 -j DNAT --to 172.17.0.10
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

But it doesn't work because external PC still cannot get access to 10.32.230.61, but can get access to 10.32.230.90. What's the solution?

```
(From a certain PC, which IP is, for example, 10.32.230.95)
# ping 10.32.230.90
PING 10.32.230.90 (10.32.230.90) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.32.230.90: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=280 ms
64 bytes from 10.32.230.90: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=336 ms
^C
# ping 10.32.230.61
(Timeout..)
```

I am sure that there is no IP confliction: 10.32.230.61 is not used by any other hosts.

Comment: Can you please clarify: it sounds like at this stage you can't even ping the second NIC at the public IP address, correct? So, at this stage your problem is not yet with Docker.

Comment: the secondary IP (10.32.230.61) can be pinged before two iptable rules are added, but once adding the above two iptable rules, ping(10.32.230.61) log become timeout, then I use "iptables -D PREROUTING .." to remove the added rules, ping turn back to alive.

Comment: and I am also sure that "ping 172.17.0.10" is okay all the time, no matter the rules are added or removed.

Comment: what happens when you map the external IP to the ports you're interested in directly to the container: `docker run ... -p 10.32.230.61:<portnum>:<portnum> ...` ? Can you `curl` to your container at `<portnum>`?

Comment: One additional comment: Have a look at [link](https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/), especially their setup and troubleshooting instructions. I noticed that their approach to ensure NAT between external IP and an internal container IP is different from yours. Maybe try their approach?

Comment: Thanks for your comments!